# Redirect GET form with action in another url

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form with the action set to "/resutls". But i have a txt input and i want to check if that is not empty to redirect to another location than "/results". Is this possible?
Code example as below:

```
<form id="results" action="/results" method="get">
<select id="country" name="country">
....
</select>
<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Apply Search" name="submit">
</form>
```

Any ideas? Can this be done with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do that in the submit  handler. **Warning:** I wouldn't give a form control a `name` of `id`. It does cause confusion: if `this` refers to the form, should `this.id` refer to the `id` of the form or the text field with `name="id"`?

```
    if( !!this.somefield.value ) { //did not want to write this.id.value !!!!
      this.action = '/other-url';
    } else {
      this.action = '/results';
    }
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#results').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // just so we can see that form action changes
    if( !!this.somefield.value ) {
      this.action = '/other-url';
    } else {
      this.action = '/results';
    }
    alert( this.action );
    //$(this)[0].submit(); //now submit the form
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="results" action="/results" method="get">
<select id="country" name="country">
</select>
<input type="text" name="somefield">
<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Apply Search" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Could provide a jsfiddle demo depicting the issue? Maybe you used $(this).submit() instead of this.submit() or $(this)[0].submit()

Comment: I don't see any recursion on the page but this line `this.action = '/full-result' + pid.value;` should be `this.action = '/full-result' + this.pid.value;` or `this.action = '/full-result/' + this.pid.value;` ... you're missing a `this.` in `pid.value`.

Comment: On the website i have this error in jquery.min.js too much recursion

...handle)||(g=r.handle=function(b){return typeof n!==U&&n.event.triggered!==b.type...

I changed that line and still got the same issue.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Please replace the jquery file with `jquery.js` so you can share something more meaningful. Without isolating the cause of the issue, you do know it would be hard for me to try looking for a solution, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63437/discussion-between-paranoid-and-peterka).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  Just set the form element's action property using jQuery `.prop()`.

As a simple example:

```
var valid = false;
// go though validation here

if (false === valid) {
    $('#results').prop('action', '/some/url/to/redirect/to');
}
```

Comment: so it will work both ways? When the txt input is empty it will make the redirect to "/results" and when its not it will redirect to "some/other/url" ??

Comment: @paranoid Well you have to put in your logic to determine when to change the form's action, but yes you can change the action as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 provides the "required" attribute wich will prevent the form for being posted, use it like this

```
<input type="text" name="id" required="required">
```

or, if you prefer to redirect to other page instead, you can do this

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $("#results").submit(function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if($("#results input[name='id']").length < 1){
                window.location.href = "your detiny url";                    
            }
            else{
                this.submit();
            }
        });
    </script>
```